How to remove adhesive from landscaping stones?
How do I remove adhesive from landscaping stones that were stacked?
I have large landscaping stones that stacked and had glued together.

This may depend on the adhesive. Please edit into your question what kind of adhesive was used.

Why bother?   The adhesive is likely on the surfaces no one sees.  If you want to get it flatter for the next gluing, I would try a wide flat scrapper or wide flat chisel with a hammer.
